Redirect guests from WooCommerce checkout to My account login and back to checkout once logged in
I use the following code (pasted in my theme functions.php file) to redirect unlogged users from checkout page to WooCommerce My Account login form:
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_specific_page' );
function redirect_to_specific_page() {
    if ( is_page('finalizar-compra') && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_redirect( 'https:/miweb.pe/login', 301 );
        exit;
    }
}

How can I redirect users, once they got logged in, back to the previous URL?
Here, the previous URL would be: https://miweb.com/finalizar-compra.
I've tried using https://miweb.pe/login/?redirect_to=https://miweb.pe/finalizar-compra, but it doesn't work.

In WooCommerce checkout, you can directly log in without any redirection, but it requires enabling the option from WooCommerce settings > Accounts and Privacy >
Guest checkout:

Then in the checkout page you will have something like:

Now if you wish making redirections, try the following modular and complete code, to redirect users, once they got logged in, back to the checkout URL from My account:
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_specific_page' );
function redirect_to_specific_page() {
    $is_checkout_page = is_checkout() && !is_wc_endpoint_url();

    if ( !is_user_logged_in() && $is_checkout_page ) {
        global $wp;

        $redirect_to = '/?redirect_to=' . urlencode( site_url( $wp->request ) );
        
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id')) . $redirect_to );
        exit();
    }
}

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin).
